# Controlling Wireless Connections

Tags: wireless-networking, security

I have a wireless router, and I share my wireless connection privately with my relatives. And I want to have control over the connection. Example, I want to close an established connection between one of the computers connected on my wireless and a suspicious host, without interrupting the connection with other trusted hosts.

What I'm trying to say is, as I read connection details in my router, I found out somebody is connecting from taiwan through port 32356. It's a bit weird so I want to get rid of that. Also, to prevent them from downloading large files (slows down my connection, since I own the router, I have right to do this correct?).

Is there a software or any way I can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite likely one of your relatives has an infected computer, and you are suggesting treating the symptoms rather than the cause.

If you can locate who it is, disinfecting his computer before he infects all of the family is first priority.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can login to your wireless router as admin, just check to make sure that port ( or any other strange ones ) are not being forwarded.

Comment: Using UPnP, ports can be opened dynamically without router configuration.

Comment: Great point. Turn off UPnP support while you are in there.